# Can't find sound played when an item is dragged

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssound

I am trying to search that sound that is played when you drag an item to a finder window. I searched in /System/Library/Sounds and I've found these:

> Basso.aiff
>   Blow.aiff
>   Bottle.aiff
>   Frog.aiff
>   Funk.aiff
>   Glass.aiff
>   Hero.aiff
>   Morse.aiff
>   Ping.aiff
>   Pop.aiff
>   Purr.aiff
>   Sosumi.aiff
>   Submarine.aiff
>   Tink.aiff

But none of these is the one I search. I also searched on ~/Library/Sounds but the folder is empty. According to the documentation there should be some also to /Library/Sounds and /Network/Library/Sounds, but these folders don't even exist on my file system. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the sound you are looking for, go to

/Macintosh HD/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component

(right-click to show package contents) then

Contents/SharedSupport/System Sounds/system

It is called "Volume Mount.aif"